Can't show alert to user
In an iOS app, when the user denies location permission, I want to show an alert to give permission. I debug it and code works successfully but I can't see any alert in the simulator.
I start the program and deny location permission. I then restart it and I can't show any alert.
func checkLocationAuthorizationStatus() {
    let status = locationManager.authorizationStatus

    switch status{
    case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways: //eğer iki izinden biri alınmış ise burası çalışıcak
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    case .denied, .restricted: //red yemiş ise burası çalışıcak
        showLocationAccessAlert()
    case .notDetermined: //henüz konum izni vermemiş
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    @unknown default:
        break
    }
}

func showLocationAccessAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(
        title: "Konum Erişimi Gerekli",
        message: "Lütfen Ayarlar'dan konum iznini etkinleştirin.",
        preferredStyle: .alert
    )
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ayarlar", style: .default) { _ in
        if let settingsURL = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(settingsURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    })
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Vazgeç", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


have you tried to show in main thread?
DispatchQuee.main.async { ... }

and other question, at which time do you execute the func checkLocationAuthorizationStatus?

You need to show us how your function is being called. As Andres pointed out, if you call it from a background thread it won't work reliably. Also, what class is this code from? (A UIViewController subclass, I would assume?) How is the view controller invoked, and are you sure it is an on-screen instance of the view controller? (The issue is likely in the code you didn't show - how your function is being called, and from where.)

One other reason why your alert isn't shown, occurs when the actual presenting view controller (which is either self or the next eligible  ancestor in the view controller hierarchy) is already presenting another view controller. You might add some assertions to check this. It's a nasty error. It can also be a race with this other view controller being in the process of dismissing.

Solution
Use CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus (or locationManager.authorizationStatus in iOS 14+) to determine the current location permission status.
Display an Alert: If the permission status is .denied or .restricted, show an alert that explains why location access is needed, with an option to open the app’s settings.
Open App Settings: In the alert, add a button that opens the app's settings where users can manually enable location permissions.
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class YourViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        checkLocationAuthorizationStatus()
    }

    func checkLocationAuthorizationStatus() {
        let status = locationManager.authorizationStatus

        switch status {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways:
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        case .denied, .restricted:
            showLocationAccessAlert()
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }

    func showLocationAccessAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(
            title: "Location Access Required",
            message: "Please enable location permissions in Settings to use this feature.",
            preferredStyle: .alert
        )

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default) { _ in
            if let settingsURL = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(settingsURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }
        })

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        checkLocationAuthorizationStatus()
    }
}

Additional Tips
Test on a Real Device: Simulators sometimes behave inconsistently with location permissions, so testing on an actual device is recommended.
